# Error While Creating Site Collection

Tags: 2010, content-type, site-collection

I am creating Site Collection with Team Site Template. When I tried to create it shows me error that

> The parent content type specified by content type identifier 0x0101
>   does not exist.

Note : After I tried to create Custom Content Type which inherits Document Content Type I got this error.

Answer (score 1):

Please activate 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' feature first, to activate the feature go to team site, site action -> site settings -> site collection feature (under Site Collection Administration group) and find 'SharePoint Server Publishing Infrastructure' activate it, please check and let me know if it worked

Comment: I said when I Create Team Site it is showing error. So how can I Activate Publishing Feature from Central Admin Site Creating Wizard?

Comment: Ok got it, but one thing is confusing me at what moment you are getting the error - at the time of site creation or at the time of content type creation?

Comment: Thanx Diptarag, 

I got the solution. I find that there was mistake in my code so that's why I was getting error. I changed the code and error was gone.